# how to override an exception

Tags: python, selenium

I am writing a python / selenium script that trawls a website to find elements then ultimately write these element values to a table.

When it identifies that the element does not exist, it throws the **NoSuchElementException** as expected.

I have been trying to figure out how to override this exception, to instead, populate the table with a default value e.g. 'No Value'.

Problem is, python seems to ignore whatever I try, only to throw the exception regardless, resulting in the script execution ending prior to the table being able to be populated.

Any ideas?

```
file_1.py

def getAttributes(self):
...
...
...
try: 
    score = box.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'dealClass').get_attribute('innerHTML').strip()  
    if not score:
        raise NoSuchElementException(f"Score does not currently exist for {name}, as of {datetime.today()}") 
except NoSuchElementException as e: 
    print('Exception is: ', e)
    # Writing remediating code here but it never seems to work..
    raise
...




file_2.py

def reportResults(self):
...
    searchResults = self.find_element(By.ID, 'search_results_table') 
    report = ReportSearchResults)
    table = PrettyTable(field_names=["Name", "Price", "Score"])
    table.align["Name"] = "l"
    table.align["Price"] = "l"
    table.align["Score"] = "r"
    table.add_rows(report.getAttributes())
    print(table) 
...
```

Comment: You are catching the exception, but then you re-raise it. I think you want something like `score = 'No Value'` instead, as if that's what `box.find_element` returned.

Comment: It only ends the script if you *reraise* the exception and fail to catch it again. Get rid of the `raise` from the exception handler: you've handled it.

Comment: Thanks chepner, this works to the extent where the try: clause throws the expected exception and the except: clause now assigns the default 'score. I've also used the raise clause within the except to pass this default score up to the parent /calling function. 

However. again, as always, this exception subsequently ends the whole script prematurely with a stacktrace, where ideally, I want it to 'behave itself' and continue on with the remaining method calls in the main script.. 

Maybe I am missing some fundamental point of how exception handling is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

When you catch the exception, you can "fix" it by giving `score` a value. There's no need to reraise the exception at that point; you've handled it, so let your script proceed as if nothing happened.

```
def getAttributes(self):

    ...

    try: 
        score = box.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'dealClass').get_attribute('innerHTML').strip()  
        if not score:
            # You're going to catch it, and you don't really need
            # a long message telling you what went wrong. *You* raised
            # this one, and you know why, and you're going to fix it.
            raise NoSuchElementException("no score") 
    except NoSuchElementException as e: 
        score = 'No value'

    ...
```

Comment: Mate, thankyou, your logic helped me to figure it out. 

I also looked at https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp which has a  simple explanation of how to define your exception handling. 
Cheers for help.